# Cant call a method in Invoke

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this weird issue where I am trying to call a method in `Invoke` but it does not work for some reason IDK what am I doing wrong

```
public void EndGame ()
{
    if (GameHasEnded == false)
    {
      GameHasEnded = true;
      UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Game Over");
      Invoke("Restart",2f);
    }
    void Restart ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this script I get a message

> Trying to Invoke method:  `GameManager.Restar`t Couldn't be called"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is your method nested inside the `EndGame` method?

It should rather be

```
public void EndGame ()
{      
    if (!GameHasEnded)
    {
        GameHasEnded = true;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Game Over");
        Invoke(nameof(Restart), 2f);  
    }
}

private void Restart ()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for some reason I forgot about that  I feel so dumb right now lol